# Assign password hash to wordpress user after accidentally deleting password

Tags: php, wordpress, hash

I've accidentally updated some user passwords to have an empty string `''`.

From a database backup I have the hashed values of their passwords. How can I assign these hashed values back to their account? The wp-cli for update seems to send a email for an update and I don't want that.

I've tried updating it via SQL but it does not seem to work.

```
update wp_users set user_pass = '$2a$14$pdLULKQeENo0j7ad6U4QuOHqgo6DmaQiB4wAhYZMEGguYGqQNIaIa'
where user_email = 'test@email.com' and user_pass = '';
```

Comment: I've tried updating it via SQL but it does not seem to work. - should work

Comment: restore the backup of the user's table

Comment: How is the password, hashed? `password_hash()`?

Comment: @mr.void I put an example of how I'm updating the password with the hash.   How does it now It's a hash and that my password isn't just a really long string?

Comment: @met_k In fact, when you log on, you don't compare password but you compare hash of those. Like hash('password') == password_from_database.

Comment: That will won't work for sure... all you can do is just updated every user's password to a default password, when they try to login the password they know will be incorrect they will eventually press forget password link then ur problem solved

Comment: In detail a hash is a very long string. Your example how to update is correct

Comment: There is NO REASON why, if you have the HASH from a backup you could not UPDATE the users `user_pass` with the HASHES you get from the backup. Try using `phpMyAdmin` or whatever tool you normally use to fiddle with databases

Comment: The only problem with doing this is if the user has changed their password since whenever you took the backup

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought of that too. I'm also going to do a check for `and user_pass = '';` That should do it, right?

Comment: If you broke the data and can't recover it on your own, the least responsibility you should accept is sending out a notification email.